# JavaScript cookie management with JAX-RS

Tags: java, javascript, cookies, jax-rs

I'm sure this is something basic that I'm missing.

On my server side, I'm setting a basic cookie, right now it's a POC but the idea is that we set a token on the client that represents the session and that will be sent on subsequent requests.  I've successfully been able to send the cookie to the client.

`Set-Cookie:StrtUsername=supp1395843137929@foobar.com;Version=1;Path=`

Which to me looks right (note, it's not secured yet).  However it looks like on subsequent requests the cookie isn't getting sent along.  I even went the route of bypassing things like HttpOnly to ensure that the javascript that makes the HTTP Request isn't blocked.  Is there another way to ensure that cookies are always sent?

Note that this issue didn't occur when I was using Java's JSESSIONID.  It only happens when I use a custom cookie.  Also, I can confirm that cross domain is not an issue here.  I am using nginx to host my javascript based front end, which also has `proxy_pass` enabled for my JBoss AS 7.1.1 backend.  All traffic to localhost:8080 follows this route, and the URIs for my rest API all proxied.  I assume that `Path=` just means its for all paths.

Answer (score 0):

So, in case anyone comes into this.  Turns out that `Path=` is bad.  Needed to be `Path=/;`